# Defining logical connectives by properties of consequence relations

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic

Has anyone or any text defined consequence relations that have a special property? What I mean is, suppose we are working with an abstract consequence relation $C$. I want to read a text that defines logical connectives, like conjunction and disjunction, from properties of $C$. For an example of what I mean, suppose there is a binary function $f$ on formulas of $C$, such that the following three properties hold:

1. $f(X,Y)$ is a consequence of $\{X,Y\}$
2. $X$ is a consequence of $f(X,Y)$
3. $Y$ is a consequence of $f(X,Y)$

Then it would be fair to say that $f$ is a "conjunction-like operator". Conditions on $f$ could also be defined that would make it a "disjunction-like operator", or a "conditional-like operator". I want to know, has anyone done something like this in some book or paper?

Comment: Don't your properties imply that $f(X, Y)$ *is* the conjunction $X \land Y$?

Comment: @LSpice Not necessarily. For example, if we have a propositional language that has only conditional and negation, then $f(X,Y)$ could be $\neg (X \rightarrow \neg Y)$. Also, we are working with an abstract consequence relation, so it may not have a symbol for conjunction.

Comment: What I mean to say is, in any reasonable consequence structure—I don't know the names of these things—with conjunction, $f$ is conjunction; and, in any reasonable consequence structure without conjunction *a priori*, then there is at most one such $f$ (not syntactically, but up to some notion of equivalence), and it deserves to be called conjunction.  But, since I don't know what a consequence structure is or its axioms, maybe that's not true.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a body of active research on consequence relations that admit definable connectives with abstract properties that make them behave like implications, disjunctions, etc. in some respects. See e.g. the monograph

Petr Cintula, Carles Noguera, *Logic and implication: An introduction to the general algebraic study of non-classical logics*, Trends in Logic 57, Springer, 2021, xxii+465 pp., doi [10.1007/978-3-030-85675-5](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-85675-5).

Comment: That's an answer, I up-vote it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that an article by Andrzej Grzegorczyk, An Approach to Logical Calculus, Studia Logica, 1972. ( https://www.jstor.org/stable/20014636 ) presents the described approach. Grzegorczyk defines, for a given connective $f(X,Y)$, conditions on a consequence relation, under which $f(X,Y)$ may be called a conjunction of $X$ and $Y$ etc. Then, Grzegorczyk proves (Theorems 1 and 2) that the set of theorems of a such defined system contains all intuitionistic tautologies (under a translation).